# @font-face not loading in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face, umbraco, mime-types

I have generated an @font-face kit from fontsquirrel.com for one of our client's sites. We have the site running on a staging (http) and live (https) server. The site is built on .NET

The issue I'm having is that the font does not load on IE8. It works fine in IE9, Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

The steps I took are as follows:

- Generated kit using .TTF font file supplied by the client
- Copied font files into assets folder
- Referenced font files in CSS file using the generated `@font-face` code (below)

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    src: url('../../fonts/font-name-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../../fonts/font-name-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../fonts/font-name-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../fonts/font-name-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../fonts/font-name-webfont.svg#font-name') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I've been researching possible fixes and have, so far, tried the following unsuccessfully:

- Re-generated the font kit
- Checked all required mime types are set in Web.config
- Checked the font-family rule is being picked up in IE using developer tools
- Checked the declaration is not being overridden in other CSS files
- Added the downloaded font kit test to a staging server and tested in IE8

**Note:**
The test I uploaded to the staging server is working fine on IE8. This would suggest that either it's server-related or that there's something amiss in our CSS. I'm 99% sure I've ruled out anything fishy in the CSS, though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Especially since you suspect this to be server-related, posting a URL would be essential. It would also be better to use the real font name and identify the source of the font. With the given information, the problem appears to be unanalyzable.

Comment: I'm afraid we can't post the URL — the site isn't live yet. The site uses [Umbraco](http://www.umbraco.com) (which should make no difference) but the HTML and CSS are all quite normal; the CMS isn't doing anything that might mess them up.

Comment: You say the live site is using https, have you tried the test on the live server or testing on a staging that uses SSL?

Comment: It's happening in both our Live and Staging versions when rendered under SSL, plus on Staging when rendered _without_ SSL. (The Live server redirects non-SSL'd requests.)

Comment: Not as of yet, though the issue is apparent on both secure and non-secure servers. I'll be able to add the test to the live server tomorrow and will update my post with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would check that the font files are actually being served. It could be as silly as a relative path not being correct - although in this case I doubt it. Use a tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for this. These tools should always be the first port of call for checking that files are being served as expected.

I would also check that the extensions/mime types are set up in the site's config, or in IIS's config.

Comment: The mime types are all setup correctly and I'm pretty sure our paths are correct as other browsers are pulling the font in ok. Good call on Fiddler though - I will check that now. Hopefully our test (mentioned above) will give us a clue on this. Thanks!

Comment: I would also check where you have the CSS set up in the project structure. Umbraco uses a ClientDependency library to cache certain files served by the site, including the CSS set up _within_ Umbraco itself. If the CSS is independent of Umbraco then this won't be a problem.

Comment: The issue was indeed that the .eot files were not loading. The build action for .eot files in our .csproj was set to "None" instead of "Content" by default so naturally they weren't loading. Answer accepted and many thanks!